# Url.Action Passing string array from View to Controller in MVC#

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, url-routing

I have a method that returns an array (`string[]`) and I'm trying to pass this array of strings into an Action.Currently I can't pass my parameters. I am new in MVC3. 
Pls let me know why I can't pass parameter to ActionResult..I already define ActionResult with Same parameter name.. 
thanks all in advance....

```
$('#export-button').click(function () {

            var columnLength = $("#grid")[0].p.colNames.length;
            var columnNames = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < columnLength; i++) {
                if ($("#grid")[0].p.colModel[i].hidden == false) {
                    columnNames = columnNames + $("#grid")[0].p.colModel[i].name + ',';
                }
            }
            var Val1 = jQuery(txt_search1).val();
            alert(Val1); alert(columnNames);
            document.location = '@Url.Action("OrgDataExport","Search", new { Val1 = Val1 , columnNames = columnNames})';


        });
```

Comment: array insted of new '{ Val1 = Val1 , columnNames = columnNames}'?

Comment: instead of messy querystring why not push items to javascript array and post to server? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290131/javascript-how-to-create-an-array-of-object-literals-in-a-loop    and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116099/send-array-to-mvc-controller-via-json

Comment: Thanks for all of your quick response..
@Govind.. I want to pass Val1 and ColumnName[string] array to Server..
My expression is incorrect.. pls show me How to pass to these values to Server via javascript. Thanks.

Comment: with ajax, URL not change to New View ... My want is currently on ://Localhost/search/OrganizationSearch and I want to go ://localhost/search/OrgDataExport . so I use Url.Action method.. to go New URL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#export-button').click(function () {

    var columnLength = $("#grid")[0].p.colNames.length;

    // columnNames is an object now
    var columnNames = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < columnLength; i++) {
        if ($("#grid")[0].p.colModel[i].hidden == false) {
            columnNames[i] = $("#grid")[0].p.colModel[i].name;
        }
    }

    var Val1 = jQuery(txt_search1).val();

    document.location = "Home/Index/" + $.param({ Val1 = Val1 , columnNames = columnNames });
});
```

Your action that takes `columnNames` as a string array

```
public ActionResult Index(string val1, string[] columnNames)
{
// Your code
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If the URL becomes too big you can submit the values through form using POST method. If your view already have a form use that else create a dynamic one on the fly and submit the values through POST.

```
$('#export-button').click(function () {

    var Val1 = jQuery(txt_search1).val();    

    $("#hidden-form").remove();

    // create a form dynamically
    var form = $('<form>')
            .attr({ id: "hidden-form",
              action: "/Home/Index",
              method: "post",
              style: "display: none;"
            })
            .appendTo("body");            

    // add the "Val1" as hidden field to the form.
    $('<input>').attr({ name: "Val1 ", value: Val1, type: "hidden" }).appendTo(form);

    var columnLength = $("#grid")[0].p.colNames.length;

    // add the "columnNames" as hidden fields to the form
    for (var i = 0; i < columnLength; i++) {
        if ($("#grid")[0].p.colModel[i].hidden == false) {
            var t = $("#grid")[0].p.colModel[i].name;
            $('<input>').attr({ name: "columnNames", value: t, type: "hidden"
             }).appendTo(form);
        }
    };

    // submit the form
    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: Hi @Mark.. thank for your code sample.. It work for me..only i need to edit abit.."Index?" + $.param({ Val1 : Val1 , columnNames : columnNames }); Pls let me know one thing, can i hide my parameter from url. bcos now in url, my parameter is too long.. any suggestion?
waiting ur reply,

Comment: That's a real problem. I would suggest you to submit the values to the sever through a HTML form using POST.

Comment: can u show me any sample codes or pls refer me any post . this is my first exp... thanks in advance..

Comment: I updated the answer. If you already have a form in your view utilize that else create a dynamic one as I did above.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for your code.it work. Let me know one thing, Can i return View() with new window? pls suggest me something..

Comment: Do you want to open the view returned in the form post in new window?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Mark..Now I got the ans..by adding "target: "_blank"," to form attribute. in your code.. Cheers.!.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < columnLength; i++) {
                if ($("#grid")[0].p.colModel[i].hidden == false) {
                    columnNames = columnNames + $("#grid")[0].p.colModel[i].name + ',';
                }
            }
            var Val1 = jQuery(txt_search1).val();
            alert(Val1); alert(columnNames);
            document.location = '@Url.Action("OrgDataExport","Search", new { Val1 = Val1 , columnNames = columnNames})';
```

Hi Louis,

Your are trying to access javascript varaibles Val1 and columnNames from the server side tag and it is not possible. For more details, please refer this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989993/access-javascript-variable-in-razor-code).

You can do it by following way.

```
    var jsonData = { val1 : Val1, columnNames : columnNames };

$.ajax({
          type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                url: "Home/Index", // Location of the service
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
                processdata: true, //True or False
                success: function () {
                  alert("success")
                }
       });
```

On your controller side you have to write like

```
public ActionResult Index(string val1, string columnNames)
{
// Your code
}
```

Comment: @alok_dida.."columnNames" var is just string. i query from jquery gird selected columns. when i printout it, it got the value like "col1,col2,col3,col4". so i want to send this string to controller . now i testing as u suggest . with ajax. thanks.

Comment: with ajax, URL not change to New View ... My want is currently on ://Localhost/search/OrganizationSearch and  I want to go ://localhost/search/OrgDataExport . so I use Url.Action method.. to go New URL..

Comment: @Louismm . You can use directly use <Javascript Code Start> window.location = '://localhost/search/OrgDataExport?Val1='+val1+'&columnNames='+columnNames; <Javascript Code End> on your export button click event. Please have a look http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Answer (score 0):

You tagged JQuery-Ajax but i don't see any ajax attempt in the code example? So i am guessing you want to know an Ajax orientated solution. You're probably not using Zend Framework, but i hope this answers helps point you in the right direction to a solution.

From JS/Zend framework experience you could look at something like

```
$('#export-button').click(function () {
   ....
   var actionUrl= "/controller/action/";
   $.ajax({
      url: actionUrl,
      data: {
        variable1: "OrgDataExport",
        variable2: "Search",
        Val1: Val1,
        columnNames: columnNames            
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(json) {
        //do stuff
      }
   });
   ....
});
```

In the ZendFramework controller you can then grab the variables on the request:

```
$Val1 = $this->_request->getparam("Val1");
```

Comment: He also tagged his question with `asp.net-mvc-3`, not `php` or `zend`. In addition to that  `'Val1' => Val1` is invalid javascript.

Comment: Perfectly correct @DarinDimitrov, thanks for pointing that out (upvoted it). I am aware Louis hadn't tagged php or Zend, but that is just the implementation of MVC for the JQuery-Ajax related answer I gave. :)

Comment: @logansama.. Thanks for ur reply.. I want to use javascript code inside .cshtml to Controller.cs in MVC3.